# Eigenkets of a two-state hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, linear-algebra

I have a question related to this other question: [Eigenenergies and eigenkets given the Hamiltonian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100842/). In it, OP is given the following hamiltonian:

$$
H=a(|1\rangle \langle1|-|2\rangle\langle2|+|1\rangle\langle2|+|2\rangle\langle1|)
$$

and is asked to find the eigenstates of $H$ ($a$ is a number). In order to do so, they write $H$ in matrix form and solve from there. A key part in the process however, is using that the kets $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ form an orthonormal basis of the eigenstate space of H. I do not understand what allows them to make this last statement.

Comment: They are orthonormal by definition. You can always find an orthonormal basis of a vector space and just write the Hamiltonian in that basis.

Comment: it follows from the fact that the Hamiltonian is hermitian/self adjoint

Comment: In a finite dimensional space you can always select an orthonormal basis by recursively using a Gram-Schmidt process to produce a sequence of orthonormal vectors.  This guarantees that your Hamiltonian will have a representation as a hermitian matrix (or actually it's the reverse: if your Hamiltonian is to be hermitian w/r to some inner product, the basis states must be orthonormal w/r to this inner product.)

Comment: In quantum mechanics, *especially* in QM courses, we often just assume that we have an orthonormal basis (because one can always be found). So any time you see something like the Hamiltonian above, you can just make the assumption that the two states are orthogonal (and normalized), *unless told otherwise*.